# Shell command via ProcessBuilder fails to do anything on MacOS, but exit code == 0 and no errors

Tags: java, macos, runtime.exec

So I have been trying to find a solution to this problem for quite a while now but haven't been able to even get an error message. I am trying to toggle the dark mode on MacOS with this command: `/usr/local/bin/dark-mode on`

It works if I execute it with the standard terminal, but executing the code below doesn't do anything. The log file is empty. To make sure my code is correct I used a different command (commented out) and this one gave me the correct output to `whoami` and returned my current user.

I thought this may have to do with application security on MacOS? I have no idea where to start though.

```
private void switchDark() {
    try {
        //Activate the dark mode on MacOS
        String command = new String[] { "/usr/local/bin/dark-mode", "on" };
        //String command = new String[] { "whoami" }; //This works and gives me the current user

        ProcessBuilder pb =
                 new ProcessBuilder(command[0], command[1]);
        File log = new File("LOG.txt");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));
        Process proc = pb.start();

        proc.waitFor();

        if(proc.exitValue() != 0) {
            throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
        }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException | IllegalThreadStateException ex) {
        System.out.println("Setting dark mode failed!");
        if(debug)System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I'm assuming, since the command doesn't exist on my Mac, you're using [sindresorhus/dark-mode](https://github.com/sindresorhus/dark-mode)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, exactly. It works when I manually run the command.

Comment: *"The log file is empty"* - Since `dark-mode on/off` doesn't generate any output, I'm not surprised. May try `dark-mode status` instead.  When I run it, it works fine for me

Comment: Did you run my application or dark-mode? dark-mode works for me when running from terminal.

Comment: I was able to get all the commands to work

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the code to see what that "dark-mode" command does.  (https://github.com/sindresorhus/dark-mode - thanks @MadProgrammer)

I'm no Swift or MacOS expert, but that command's implementation doesn't look like it tests if the AppleScript command succeeded.  Furthermore, there doesn't seem to be anything to set non-zero exit status in the event of a failure.

So my conclusion is that the underlying AppleScript command is not working ... for reasons that are not reported ... and that information is not passed back to Java via the exit status.  There is nothing you can do about it at the Java level.

My guess is that the "dark mode" request is actually failing for permissions-related reasons.

Comment: Thats interesting, thanks! Is it possible I need to call a bash shell before executing my command? Something like command = { "/bin/bash", "/usr/local/bin/dark-mode", "on" } so I have the necessary environment variables? Or on a different approach, would it be dark-mode or my application that needs the automation permission?